# Query multiple nodes for Recycler View?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have my Firebase DB setup like so,

[image]

I want to retrieve the childs pointed to by the blue arrows. They are the last messages in each chat. I want to use the values to fill a RecyclerView. However, in order to retrieve all the last messages in each chat I have to do multiple queries and the RecyclerView requires a single query. Or so it seems to be the case from what I've googled so far.

Another solution I tried was to create a ListView and fill it with a custom adapter. Then by doing multiple queries I can fill a list and use that instead of a query. However, in order to fill the list I need to make it final in the local scope of a snapshot. That doesn't work because I have two snapshots.

I have thought of simply redesigning my DB however, I can't think of a way to do it without making the DB unorganized. Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this with your current data structure is, as you've already noticed, with a separate query for each node under `chat`.

As usual with NoSQL databases, the solution is to modify/augment the data model to make the use-case easier. In this case, I'd store the information you need directly under a new top-level node.

```
lastChatMessages: {
  "0hV9...Ri83": {
    ...
  },
  "IZsn...QHn2": {
    ...
  }
}
```

So whenever you add a new message to `/chats`, you also set the same information in `/lastChatMessages` with the same first-level child ID.

This sort of data duplication is quite common in NoSQL databases. If that's new to you, I'd recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/), watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s), and possible also [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video). That last one is for Cloud Firestore, but most concepts apply to many NoSQL databases.

Comment: Thank you for you response! I was thinking about doing the lastChatMessages as you suggested, but felt like it might be considered bad programming or DB design for that matter. I will utilize that method now.